# Write permission for Guest Session

Tags: permissions, directory, guest-session

What permissions should I set to a directory to make it accessible in read-write mode for *Guest Session*? I don't want to make it writable for everyone, just only for *Guest Session*, so simple:

`chmod o+rwx`

does not satisfy me. Is there a group for *Guest Session* permissions, that I can use?

Comment: Why do you want that? Anyone can log in as guest and write to the directory anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a group for the purpose:

```
sudo addgroup --system guests
```

Make the temporary guest users be added to that group by editing or creating the file `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh` and adding this line:

```
adduser $USER guests
```

Create the directory `/var/guest-data` like this:

```
sudo mkdir -m 2775 /var/guest-data
sudo chgrp guests /var/guest-data
```

See also the [general guidance on how to customizing the guest session feature](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).

Comment: Is there something special about /var for guest users? I tried to give permissions for all to read my /data folder, but still in guest session I can't ls the folder due to permission denied error, whereas I can ls /var/guest-data without a problem.

Comment: @jarno: Yes. The access for a guest user is deliberately restricted to certain files/folders. `/var/guest-data` is an [exception](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Save_files_on_disk).

Comment: The link does not explain why it does not work when I create e.g. `/guest-data` instead similarly: `sudo mkdir -m 0777 /guest-data`. I can not `ls /guest-data` in guest session.

Comment: @jarno: You didn't ask **why**. It's by design. `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`.

Comment: I got the impression you used the link as an explanation why `/var/guest-data` is an exception. But the `lightdm` file seems to explain that, so thanks.